# Cannot printout string length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have encountered a very strange problem today, and need to seek help here.

So I have the following function, with some debug printouts:

```
function allLongestStrings(inputArray) {
    console.log(inputArray);
    inputArray.sort((a,b)=> {
        return b.length-a.length;
    });
    
    console.log(inputArray);
    console.log(inputArray.length)
    console.log(inputArray[0].length)
    console.log(typeof(inputArray[1]))
    // console.log(inputArray[1].length)
}
```

The console output of this code snippet is:

```
[ 'aba', 'aa', 'ad', 'vcd', 'aba' ]
[ 'aba', 'vcd', 'aba', 'aa', 'ad' ]
5
3
string
```

When I uncomment the last line (which I tried to get the length of the string in the string array), I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at allLongestStrings (main.js on line 15:33)
    at _runwjbyf (main.js in the pre-written template:28)
    at getUserOutputs (main.js in the pre-written template:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

This must be some dumb coding mistakes, but can anyone tell me what it is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note how your .length is not in line with the array and its key. Remove the extra parenthesis and it should work `console.log(inputArray[1].length)`

Comment: No it didn't, that parenthesis was not there but added as a desperate resort. :(

I have modified the code.

Comment: is this the exact code where you have this issue? bcz the snippet in the question works as expected

Comment: actually, I was working on this: https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-3
there is only one function...
`smooth sailing => 9`

Comment: @lastr2d2, maybe it is the problem of the compiler used in that website, I ran it in https://repl.it/languages/nodejs, and there was no problem.

Comment: I doubt it. the snippet works in both a browser and node.js. if you have removed some lines from your actual code, try to look into the difference

Comment: I ran the code in another place(repl.it/languages/nodejs,) and seems everything is working :(, and in that website, I implement the code in Python3, still have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot, your code fails on a test case
`allLongestStrings(['aa'])`

In this case, the inputArray has only one element hence the `inputArray[1]` is undefined. To make your implementation robust, you might want to put some parameter checking in place.

For example what if `inputArray` is `undefined` or is not an array.
Or if the `inputArray` was gurateed to be an array, you can just remove your debug statements because the other part of your code works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store inputArray[i] in a variable and then try to console that variable.length

Comment: same error. I added `    const targetArray = inputArray[1];
    console.log(typeof(targetArray));
    console.log(targetArray.length);`